# Is using the INFO, DSECT, COPY, and OVERLAY output section types discouraged?

Tags: gcc, linker, ld

From the LD docs:

```
DSECT
COPY
INFO
OVERLAY

    These type names are supported for backward compatibility, and are rarely used. They all have the same effect: the section should be marked as not allocatable, so that no memory is allocated for the section when the program is run.
```

Does that mean that they are deprecated, or are they safe to use? Is there another, better way to achieve the same thing, i.e. forcing something to be non-allocatable?